# Switch database on the fly in cakePHP3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I would like to switch to a secondary database for testing a specific function in a controller. All the solutions I came across on the web state that I should use
`ConnectionManager::alias('test', 'default');`

Well, I did that but that doesn't seem to do the trick for me.

I wrote the following lines just to test if the database switch is succesful or not

```
$stores = TableRegistry::get('Stores')->find('list')->toArray();
debug($stores);
ConnectionManager::alias('test', 'default');
$stores = TableRegistry::get('Stores')->find('list')->toArray();      
debug($stores);
exit;
```

But the debug gives two times the exact same data, while the stores table on the testing database has other data. So database switch isn't really working.

Anyone has an idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$connection= ConnectionManager::get('test');
$result= $connection->execute('SELECT * FROM stores WHERE ...')->fetchAll('assoc');

die(debug($result));
```

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html

Edit :

```
$stores = TableRegistry::get('Stores')->find('list')->toArray();
TableRegistry::clear();
debug($stores);
ConnectionManager::alias('test', 'default');
$stores = TableRegistry::get('Stores')->find('list')->toArray();      
debug($stores);
exit;
```

Comment: I'm afraid that's not really a solution actually :)
The query I did was just a simple example. I'm not planning to write raw SQL queries for this. I need to be able to continue using the power of the Cake Query Builder.

Comment: As much for me..

Just add --->   TableRegistry::clear(); 
After your first request (before the first debug)

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right.
Had figured it out some moments ago too and that seems to do the trick :)

Thanks nonetheless! ;-)